# Frontier in a Delaunay Triangulation

Tags: cgal, delaunay

I´m working in a Delaunay triangulation. I have my own frontier that is not the convex hull polygon. I want to use the  my own frontier, instead of use the cgal convex hull. I haven´t found in the documentation how to do that. I suppouse that this should be done in the insertion of  a vertex or a edge but havent found a function to do that. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By imposing the outline you are changing the nature of the problem and turn it to a so-called **constrained** Delaunay triangulation. Check the cgal documentation about it.

Comment: @CarlosA.Rabelo: You can thank by accepting the answer.

Comment: Ok Yves. I´m doing that. I´m  inserting the edges as contrained edges but the problem is that after inserting all points there are triangules out of the my frontier. and these triangules should not exist because  they are out of the my frontier.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Then you have to edit the triangulation yourself and remove the edges that are outside your outline. Anyway, you must keep using the constrained Delaunay mode so that your edges belong to the triangulation.

Comment: That is the answer I was afraid of. But Ok, I can do this in my aplication. I just was trying to save work. Thank you very much for you explanations.